# Creating a front-end for REST API

Tags: rest, api

1. When I create a front-end that uses an API, where should all the links and initial data go?

For example: I have a front-end and on each page I want to display a login button (or when logged in - a sign out button and username), a recently added products list and a featured product. Should I respond with all the links and initial data when hitting my API's homepage - "/" ? Or (since there's a documentation) store all the links in my front-end app and make an initial request to somewhere to check if I'm logged in and so on? Or maybe other solution?

2. Let's say that my API has projects and a list of employees assigned to each of them. I can display only my own projects and only when I'm logged in (I'm using JWT tokens). Should I hit `/projects` to get my projects (the response would vary for each user but it's determined by the token passed in the request) and respond with 401 when not authenticated or should I hit `/user/Xyz/projects` and display 403 when trying to view someone else's projects?
3. Same API situation with projects and employees as above: In my front-end I will be displaying a list of projects with all the employees assigned to each of them underneath. Making a separate request to `/employees?projectId=X` for each project would mean a lot of requests. Should I just include the employees list in the _embedded section? (I'm following the HAL rule)

Comment: REST API is not for human consumption. The best thing you can do to create a REST client which adds front end features like login, etc...

Answer (score 2):

If you want your front-end to obey the [HATEOAS principle](http://www.admiraalit.nl/jarest/spec/index.htm#hateoas) (which is a part of the REST architectural pattern), then each page should correspond to a single REST API operation that provides all the data for that page. However, an API may be called a REST API even if the front-end does not obey all REST principles. In that case, you are free to design your REST API with other considerations in mind, e.g. performance, reusability, flexibility. I would recommend the latter. You may call multiple API resources for rendering a single page. Design your API resources as logically separated units, with their own responsibilities.

To answer your questions more specifically:

1. Suppose you need to call multiple resources to initialize the first page of your application. Do not store the URLs of these resources in the front-end application's config. You have two options to do it well:

   1. Provide a schema, e.g. a [Swagger schema](http://swagger.io/specification) and let your application retrieve the URLs of the initial resources from that schema. See also the [guidelines on my website](http://www.admiraalit.nl/jarest/spec).
   2. Let your base URL return a bunch of links to the resources required to initialize the first page (and maybe more links that could help initialize other applications in the future).
2. I would recommend /projects?user="Xyz".
3. I would include the employees as embedded objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In regards to 1: I meant that... should I keep all the links like /projects or /employees somewhere in my front-end's config or should I gather them all from the API by, for example, requesting home page?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that point. I have updated my answer for 1.